# Is it really energy economy to use movement sensor for turn lights on?

Tags: lighting, energy-efficiency, motion-sensor

I want to install those movement sensors in my house in replacement for the old light switch. I want to use those from elevator halls which has a 3 way switch to leave on,  leave off and leave monitoring.

The thing is: is the sensor energy consumption lower than a 15w to 25w white cold lamp in the hours that I simply leave it on when nobody is around?

These sensors are still expensive in my country. So I will install them only if it's worth the energy economy on long terms.

### Edit1:

This is the kind of sensor I am speaking of:

[image]

And this is the bulb I am speaking of:

[image]

Comment: It would depend on the sensor...

Comment: I edited the question to point on the right kind of sensor.

Comment: What is the exact model? The power consumption of a occupancy sensor tends to be low. [_Measured Field Performance and Energy Savings of Occupancy Sensors: Three Case Studies_](http://www.fsec.ucf.edu/en/Publications/html/FSEC-PF-309-96/index.htm) cites a source that states the power usage of the sensor is 0.002W for [PIR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Passive_infrared_sensor) types. The same type as the one pictured above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't find that one. Another company's model that gives numbers (after looking more - MANY don't, which seems sketchy) claims 10mA @ 24v, or 0.01A x24V = 0.24W - less than 15, yes; Quite a bit more than 0.002, though. Whether it's **actually worth buying** (since you mention that it's expensive) would depend on how much you pay for power and how many hours it would save you 14.75W (or so) - it might take many years to pay for itself, unless your power is also very expensive.

[This link](http://daysim.ning.com/page/keyword-lighting-control) has a rather more pessimistic assumption about the sensor at ~3W or so.

And [this link](http://static.schneider-electric.us/docs/Power%20Management/Lighting%20Control/Square%20D%20Occupancy%20Sensor%20Products/Ceiling%20Mounted%20Line%20Voltage%20Sensors/63249-420-367.pdf) has some specific numbers from another brand, ranging from 0.06W to 1.04W (1.04W is a dual-sensor/ ultra-sonic/PIR - highest is 0.18W for PIR only)